# Trouble understanding fork() output

Tags: c, fork, pid

Let's assume that there is a process with `PID = 1` and it runs the following code:

```
int a = fork();
int b = fork();
printf(“a: %d, b: %d\n”, a, b);
```

Let's further assume that new `PID`s will be given one by one, so the second given `PID` will be `2`, then `3` etc.

A possible output is:

```
a:2, b:3
a:2, b:0
a:0, b:4
a:0, b:0
```

I'm having some troubles trying to understand the output of the above code, e especially why `a:0, b:4` and `a:2, b:3`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You know that

> The return value is the zero in the child and the process-id number of the child in the parent, or -1 upon error.

So, let's see step by step what's happening here.

When `fork()` is called, it creates a new child with id `n`, then returns in the child `0` and in the parent `n`.

So let's suppose our process as pid `1`, when the first `fork()` is called it creates a process with pid `2`, then returns to a a value. `a` will have value `0` in the process `2` (the child), and will have value `2` in process `1` (the parent).

Then each process will call `fork()` and assign the return value to `b` in the parent process. In the child, `b` will have value `0`.

Anyway, I think this schema will simplify the comprehension:

The main starts:

```
|
|
int a = fork(); // It creates a new process, and the old one continues going
|
|-------------------------|
a = 2; /* Parent */       a = 0; // Child
|                         |
|                         |
int b = fork();           int b = fork(); // Each one create a new process
|                         |
|                         |-----------------------------|
|                         /* Child -> Parent */         // Child -> Child
|                         a = 0; b = 4;                 a = 0; b = 0
|
|
|
|
|-----------------------------|
/* Parent -> Parent */        // Parent -> Child
a = 2; b = 3;                 a = 2, b = 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

**Before first fork:**

```
PID 1 (father)
a = (not in scope yet)
b = (not in scope yet)
```

**After first fork:**

```
PID 1 (father)
a = 2
b = (not in scope yet)

PID 2 (child of 1)
a = 0
b = (not in scope yet)
```

**After second fork:**

```
PID 1 (father)
a = 2
b = 3

PID 2 (child of 1)
a = 0
b = 4

PID 3 (child of 1)
a = 2
b = 0

PID 4 (child of 2)
a = 0
b = 0
```

Comment: Thank you. It may be a simple one, but why in `PID 3`, `a = 2`? how come `a` remaind `2`?

Comment: Because 3 is a child of 1, hence a complete clone of 1 up until the second call to `fork`, including the value of `a`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not even trying to answer your question. It's more about showing the pattern which is commonly used. It might have been a comment if only there was proper code formatting in comments.

The basic construction with `fork()` is:

```
if (int PID = fork() == 0 ) {
    //it's a child process
} else {
    //it's a parent process
}
```

Using simple

```
int PID1 = fork();
int PID2 = fork();
```

is very risky as you will almost for sure receive `Race condition`.

Answer (score 1):

After a `fork`, you can be either in the father (`fork` returns the child's PID) or in the child (`fork` returns `0`).

After the first call to `fork`, you will have 2 processes: the father (`a = 2` in your example) and the child (`a = 0`).

Both will fork, the father (`a = 2`) will give a child (`b = 0`) and a new father (`b = 3`). The child (`a = 0`) will give a new child (`b = 0`) of which it will be the father (`b = 4`).

Your possible output is:

```
a:2, b:3 -> father and father
a:2, b:0 -> father and child
a:0, b:4 -> child and father
a:0, b:0 -> child and child
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Original process:
forks child A, and child B
prints `a:2, b:3`

    child A process:
    forks child BB
    prints `a:0, b:4`

        child BB proess:
        forks nothing
        prints `a:0, b:0`

    child B process:
    forks nothing
    prints `a:2, b:0`
```

And since you have not use any  `wait` or `waitpid` these can appear in any order.